# Maximum Number of images

Tags: jpeg, image-processing

How many images can be produced by all permutations of 24-bit 640x480 JPEG? Is this is the maximum number of images on 24 bit 640x480 frame and we can not have more images?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No it is not home work. I had a discussion with one of my friend.The concern is that is the number of images limited on a particular scale. I think no.

Answer (score 4):

(2^24)^(640x480)

2 choices per bit

24 bits

640 times 480 pixels

^ is exponent

~~ edit to reply to comments~~

Yes, this is the maximum number of images.

Yes, compression would decrease this number.

More basic example, to clarify:

Let's calculate how many images can be 1x2 using 2 bit color.

In 2 bit color, each pixel must be one of 4 colors. In my imaginary world, here, the choices are Black, White, Green and Yellow:  BWGY

So, for pixel 1,1, there are 4 choices.  And for pixel 1,2, there are four choices.  So here are **all** the possible pictures:

```
BB BW BG BY WB WW WG WY GB GW GG GY YB YW YG YY
```

You can calculate this by (number of choices) raised to the (number of pixels), so in this case 4^2 = 16.

Let's say we wanted to increase the width of this picture (by making it a 1x3 image. ooh: widescreen!).   For each of the original 16 pictures, you can make 4 new pictures, one for each of the color choices.  So now, you have 64 pictures.  Which still fits our formula: (choices)^(pixels) 4^3 = 64.

Another note: if you are dealing with x bits, the number of color choices will always be 2^x

Comment: Kindly answer the second question

Comment: I think he did answer your second question. You asked for the number of images by *all* permutations, which implies maximum in and of itself.

Comment: What if the object changes, texture, lightning etc changes...

Comment: While this is clearly the answer for a bitmap image of the given requirements, I suspect JPEG's lossy compression effectively reduces this value.

Comment: If anyone is interested, this value works out to `8.9542950495824726607075904256630349841435477985541... × 10^2219433` ( [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%282%5E24%29%5E%28640x480%29) ). Otherwise known as "quite a lot".

Comment: @Any:  "what if the object changes"  If the object changes, at least 1 pixel would be a different color, which would be a different one of the many possible images.

Comment: +1 to @MDA's point about lossy compression reducing this value.